# DataSpell: Module not found error import from directory

Tags: python, import, dataspell

I have two files in the same folder:

```
-- my folder
   - myfunct.py
   - merge.py
```

In merge.py I import myfunct.py. I use conda venv, when I run directly from terminal:

```
conda activate da
python merge.py
```

everything works. When instead I run from DataSpell (with the same interpreter of that virtual environment) it gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfunct'`

I have the root folder in path and the same virtual environment, the two files are in the same folder... Everything works as usual also by setting up PyCharm, what am I missing? What can I check in DS to be sure everything is setup properly?

Comment: What is "DataSpell" ? Your `myfunct.py` file ?

Comment: It is a commercial IDE https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/ just as PyCharm

Comment: Ok, didn't know that one ! When you ask PyCharm to run a script, it sets your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to include the script's directory, such that when it searches for a module it know where to look for it. Could you run `import sys ; print(sys.path)` before your `import myfunct` line ?

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in DataSpell **2022.3.2** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-4251/PyCharm-2022.3-Notebooks-cant-import-modules-from-Sources-Root

Answer (score 0):

Also note the Python file naming restrictions of not having dashes, special characters, or extra periods in the file name, though an underscore is fine.